# Select Join query

Tags: mysql, join

Use the e_store database
Write a SELECT - JOIN query that displays the following table:

```
+----+--------------+--------+-------+
| id | product_name | price  | stars |
+----+--------------+--------+-------+
|  3 | PC           | 157.40 |     3 |
|  4 | Headphones   |  20.00 |     2 |
|  4 | Headphones   |  20.00 |     5 |
+----+--------------+--------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

I have the following code

```
 SELECT 
    products.id, products.name, price, reviews.stars 
    FROM products 
    JOIN reviews 
     ON products.id = reviews.product_id 
    WHERE products.id = 3 AND 4;
```

I am only getting `products.id` 3; how can I get 3 and 4?

Comment: `id` cannot be equal to 3 _and_ 4 at the same time; it can be 3 _or_ 4 though.

Comment: MySQL is fooling you because it allows for `(a boolean condition) OR (a number)`. Any strongly typed programming language (except for a few like C) wouldn't let you write that. Most databases (PostgreSQL, for instance) wouldn't either. You can do different things... Check whether [`IN`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) can work for you. Or just *(a condition)* [`OR`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp) *(another one)*. In that particular case, you could even use [`BETWEEN`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `OR` clause. Product 3 or product 4 - try this code:

```
SELECT 
  products.id, products.name, price, reviews.stars 
FROM products 
JOIN reviews 
 ON products.id = reviews.product_id 
WHERE products.id = 3 OR products.id = 4;
```

Basically condition is applied for each single row, and you cannot setup it to have contradictions like `id = 3 AND id = 4` because you will get zero rows - that's why you need to use `or` instead.

Your condition is checking if `id = 3 and 4` *(4 is considered to be always true, so it's equals to check `id = 3`)*

After adding `or` you will get statement you want, either `id = 3`, or `id = 4`.

For more conditions is good to use `in`:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm